# I want to make an automated sliding picture gallery using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to make an automated sliding picture gallery using the JQuery plugin http://slidesjs.com/ but I don't know how to manipulate the slide.js file to make it timed, does anyone have experience in using this plugin, I'm new to this.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $("#slides").slides({
    play: 5000
  });
```

Will change slides every 5 seconds. You don't need to alter the core plugin, just look at the options/documentation on the website.

Answer (score 0):

and here is how to custom the animation duration (in ms):

```
$("#slides").slides({
    fadeSpeed: 350
});
```